# starting container process caused: exec: "[\"/bin/sh -c\"": stat ["/bin/sh -c": no such file or directory

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition, aws-fargate

I am building and deploying an application via Docker and ECS Fargate. I have my entrypoint command defined in the ECS Task definition. Upon pushing the image into a private ECR repository, I am getting this error when ECS Fargate attempts to deploy the docker image. Any advice would be helpful. Below is the dockerfile, Task Definition, and the error.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:7
COPY /src/main/build/application.zip /tmp/application.zip

COPY /src/main/residual-container-setup/application/init.sh /tmp/init.sh

#Environment variables and Entry point being defined via task definition
```

**Task Definition**

```
{
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/application",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [
        "[\"/bin/sh -c\"",
        "\"/tmp/init.sh\"]"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 9003,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 9003
        }
      ],
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "HOST",
          "value": "dev.application.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "REST_PORT",
          "value": "8003"
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [],
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/application:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "name": "application"
    }
  ]
```

**Error**

```
container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "[\"/bin/sh -c\"": stat ["/bin/sh -c": no such file or directory
```

I attempted running the container locally with the following command: `docker run -it $docker_image /bin/sh

I was unable to even exec into the container. I believe I may need to install additionally in the image to get this to work. Any advice would be helpful.

**Update**
I have updated the dockerfile to update the permissions on the init script using the following command: `chmod +x /tmp/init.sh`

I have also update the task definition entrypoint attribute to `["/bin/sh", "-c", "/tmp/init.sh"]`

After making these changes I am now being presented with the following:

```
container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "-c": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Comment: It needs to be `["/bin/sh", "-c", "/tmp/init.sh"]` -- or really, it could just be `["/tmp/init.sh"]` if your file has a shebang and execute permissions. But having all the literal quotes instead of syntactic ones is just wrong on its face, and so is having the `-c` mushed together with the `/bin/sh`.

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says: You don't have a file named `/bin/sh -c`. It's looking for a file by that name because you have the `-c` as part of the first part of the argument list, which is treated as the name of the program to run. That program is just `/bin/sh`. Its first argument should be `-c`, its second argument should be `/tmp/init.sh`. Each of these things should be a separate array entry. Hence, `["/bin/sh", "-c", "/tmp/init.sh"]`.

Comment: I have updated the dockerfile to make the init.sh executable with the following command: chmod +x /tmp/init.sh

After building the docker image and updating the entry point to [/tmp/init.sh], I am getting the following error:

container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "-c": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: That new error means you have `["-c", "/tmp/init.sh"]` without `"sh"` or `"bash"` first. If you remove the `"bash"`, you also need to remove the `"-c"`.

Comment: If I update the entrypoint to ["/tmp/init.sh"], I get presented with the following error:

standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

Comment: That's a better error than you had before. Now, what's the shebang to that file? If it doesn't start with something like `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (or `#!/bin/sh`, or so forth -- pointing to a shell that actually exists inside your container), that's the problem you need to fix next.

Answer (score 0):

Your entrypoint is defined wrongly.
The way you did it Linux thinks the path to the binary is "/bin/sh -c". If you check the container image I'm pretty sure you do not find that file either.